# urllib.urlretrieve never returns - python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

Im writing a websracping code with python which downloads images and saves them in separate files. So the code is working just fine, and images are being downloaded and being saved normally,

But sometimes, after downloading 3-8 pictures, The line #45 
stream, headers = b.urlretrieve(url) 
never returns. The call goes off but it never returns control back to the program. Any idea what may be causing this and how can I somehow continue my program once this happens?

[image: code]

Comment: Please post your code as text not as a screenshot.

Comment: Try using Requests: HTTP for Humans - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html instead!